# Find the list of "current" maxima with respect to the list index

Tags: python, list

Given a list `a`, I'd like to know all indices `i` such that `a[i]>a[j]` for all `j<i`.

I can come up with a simple for loop, but wondered whether there's some built in version of that:

```
max_values = [a[0]]
indices = [0]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x>max_values[-1]:
        indices.append(i)
        max_values.append(x)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: so you want to check for which indices only smaller values follow?

Comment: no, for which indices all left values are smaller (but it's essentially the same question, just reverse the list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't look like a function that would be needed enough to warrant a build in, and I've never seen it before.

Your question doesnt state that you need the values, only the indexes so in that case you could simplify to

```
max_value = a[0]
indices = [0]
for i, x in enumerate(a):
    if x>max_value:
        indices.append(i)
        max_value = x
```

Otherwise your code is good, nothing to improve.